# Make all element of a sequence equal

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Some tricky questions from maths. I wonder it to be puzzling question. suppose we have given a sequence consisting of n numbers. An operation is given that we can choose three  consecutive elements and add 1 to all three of them. We can perform the above operation any number of times. Is it really possible to make all the array elements equal after performing operation any number of times? Is it possible to declare yes or no just after analyzing the numbers?

Note: elements of sequence can be $10^-9  to 10^9$.
Someone please tell me which algorithm will use here.Thanks

example: suppose given sequence is   5 4 1 -1 0 3 5. We can make all elements equal by performing above operation:

One operation on index [2,3,4] and the resultant sequence will be {5 5 2 0 0 3 5}.

Three operations on index [3,4,5] and the resultant sequence will be {5 5 5 3 3 3 5}.

Two operations on index [4,5,6] and the resultant sequence will be {5 5 5 5 5 5 5}.

Comment: if all numbers don't have the same decimal part, it's impossible

Comment: Your header question makes no sense.  The question in the body looks a little better, but what is a "valid" element?  More generally, what is the source of this question?  It looks like a programming challenge.

Comment: @lulu valid here means to take only 3 consecutive elements. It is not a programming question. But will be a number theory question

Comment: So "three valid consecutive elements" just means "three consecutive elements"?  If so, I suggest removing the word "valid".  What is the source of the problem?

Comment: @lulu it is in brain teasers question of a local magazine.

Comment: @BarryCipra why you stress so much on first and second number only. Sequence can be in any order.

Comment: The sum of all the numbers modulo 3 remains the same. So if you start with, say, 9 numbers, it is possible that you will never get to all equal numbers: if you get to a configrstion with all the numbers being equal, the sum of the numbers would be zero, and if it's not the case at the beginning...it's impossible! Try with 1 2 3 ... 9 but substitute 1 with 2.

Comment: @AndreaMarino can u please explain a bit by taking example?

Comment: @AndreaMarino taking the example of my post ,sum is 17. But still it is possible to make all elements equal .

Comment: @AndreaMarino are u there? or anyone who can tell his logic for this question

Comment: in your example, the lenght of the sequence is 7, which is not a multiple of 3, thats why you don't have a contradiction with @AndreaMarino comment above

Comment: There are many counter examples.  The one I thought of is just a set with only 3 elements.  ${0,1,2}$.  You have to always pick these three since there are no other numbers to pick.

Comment: Can anyone tell in a summarize way, when it is possible to make all elements equal and when it is not?

Comment: As you have read in the comments, there are several obstructions that may arise. There could be a characterization of good pairs but could be hard. Have you an application or a concrete case in mind? It could be easier with some assumptions.

Comment: I have written all the info in my post. I don't have to say much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a straightforward algorithmic approach that will either make all the values on an $n$-tuple equal or show that it's impossible to do so.

Suppose we start with an $n$-tuple $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Since the only allowable operation is to add $1$ to three consecutive numbers, we may as well limit the discussion to $n$-tuples of *integers*. (The numbers cannot possibly be made equal if they have fractional parts that are not all equal.) Now the only operation that increases $x_1$ also increases $x_2$ and $x_3$, and likewise the two operations that increase $x_2$ also increase $x_3$. Consequently, it will be impossible to make the first three numbers equal unless $x_1\ge x_2\ge x_3$.  (Similar considerations apply at the other end as well, but we'll work from left to right.)

If $n=3$, there is really nothing to do; we either have $x_1=x_2=x_3$ or we don't. The case $n=4$ is not much more difficult: we either have $x_1\ge x_2=x_3=x_4$ or $x_1=x_2=x_3\le x_4$, in which case it's possible to make all the numbers equal, or we don't, in which case it's not possible to make the numbers all equal.

For $n\ge5$, with $x_1\ge x_2\ge x_3$, it possible to make the first three numbers equal, by adding $1$ to $(x_3,x_4,x_5)$ enough times to make $x_3=x_2$, and then adding $1$ to $(x_2,x_3,x_4)$ enough times to make $x_2=x_1$. Once we have done this, we can add $1$ to $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ as many times as we like, but we can no longer add any more $1$'s to $(x_2,x_3,x_4)$ or $(x_3,x_4,x_5)$, because doing so would leave us with $x_1\lt x_3$, which would produce an impossible situation already proscribed in the first paragraph.

The effect of this is to "detach" the first three numbers from the rest of the problem, reducing the rest of the problem to operations on the $(n-3)$-tuple $(x_4,x_5,\ldots,x_n)$.  In short, as long as we have at least $5$ numbers to work with, we can make the first three numbers equal and then deal with the remainder. Working systematically, the final remainder will have either $2$, $3$, or $4$ numbers. In the case of $2$ and $3$ remaining numbers, those numbers will either be equal or not and there's nothing one can do about it; in the case of $4$ remaining numbers, they can either be made equal or not as described earlier (in the second paragraph).

Finally, in the case of $2$ remaining numbers that are equal or $4$ remaining numbers that have been made equal, that value is either *less* than the value of one (or more) of the earlier split-off triples' values, or not. If it is (less than the greatest of the split-off values), nothing can be done; the numbers cannot all be made equal. But if it's greater than or equal to those values, then any triples who values are less can be brought up to equal it; and, clearly, in the case of $3$ remaining values, if they're equal, then all the triples can be made equal.

Demonstrating this on the OP's sequence $(5,4,1,-1,0,3,5)$, we have

$$(5,4,1,-1,0,3,5)\to(5,4,2,0,1,3,5)\to(5,4,3,1,2,3,5)\to(5,4,4,2,3,3,5)\to(5,5,5;3,3,3,5)\to(5,5,5;4,4,4,5)\to(5,5,5;5,5,5,5)$$

(where a semicolon replaces the comma to indicate the split-off triple).

Remark: Something that might be of interest here is whether there is any quick way, short of running the algorithm itself, to tell what the answer will be.

Comment: Thanks, sir for ur explanation.